# Paginación de v-card con Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

Trabajando con Vuetify, me surge la duda de como realizar una paginación de v-card. Teniendo una primera página sencilla de ejemplo como:

```html
<v-col cols="12" xs="12" sm="12" xl="12" md="12" lg="12">
  <v-row>
    <v-col v-for="c in cards" cols="12" xs="12" sm="12" xl="3" md="12" lg="3">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>{{c.num}}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle>{{c.nombre}}</v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="2"></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </v-row>
</v-col>
```

Y en JS

```
data:{
    page:1,
    cards: [
        {"num": 1, "nombre": "n1"},
        {"num": 2, "nombre": "n2"},
        {"num": 3, "nombre": "n3"},
        {"num": 4, "nombre": "n4"},
        {"num": 5, "nombre": "n5"},
        {"num": 6, "nombre": "n6"},
        {"num": 7, "nombre": "n7"},
        {"num": 8, "nombre": "n8"},
        
    ]   
  }
```

¿Cómo se podría plantear la páginación de v-card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una propiedad `computed` que contenga las cartas a mostrar y en función de la página filtra las cartas que tienes para mostrar las que corresponden:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      page:1,
      length:2,
      cards: [
        {"num": 1, "nombre": "n1"},
        {"num": 2, "nombre": "n2"},
        {"num": 3, "nombre": "n3"},
        {"num": 4, "nombre": "n4"},
        {"num": 5, "nombre": "n5"},
        {"num": 6, "nombre": "n6"},
        {"num": 7, "nombre": "n7"},
        {"num": 8, "nombre": "n8"}
      ]   
    }
  },
  computed: {
  
    shownCards () { 
    
      const { page, length, cards } = this;
      const number = Math.ceil(cards.length / length); // Numero de elementos a mostrar por página
      return cards.slice((page - 1) * number, page * number);
    
    }
  
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">

  <v-app>
  
    <v-container>
    
      <v-col cols="12" xs="12" sm="12" xl="12" md="12" lg="12">
        <v-row>
          <v-col v-for="c in shownCards" :key="c.num" cols="12" xs="12" sm="12" xl="3" md="12" lg="3">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>{{c.num}}</v-card-title>
              <v-card-subtitle>{{c.nombre}}</v-card-subtitle>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <div class="text-center">
            <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="length"></v-pagination>
          </div>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    
    </v-container>
  
  </v-app>

</div> 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```